# What car has the highest MPH in Forza Horizon 5?

Tags: forza-horizon-5

I couldn't find a solid answer for this online so I was wondering if anybody knows which car currently has the highest top speed (with or without car tuning)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this webpage](https://www.inverse.com/gaming/forza-horizon-5-best-fastest-drag-racing-cars-to-buy), the fastest car in Forza Horizon 5 is the McLaren F1 GT with a top speed of 460MPH.